# Confirm MediaPlayer automatic retry on streaming HTTP error

Tags: android, media-player

I originally posted this question to the Android developers [Google group](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-developers/HVope9HbUXM/discussion) a few days ago, but have yet to hear a response. Maybe someone on Stack Overflow can help?

I have an app which streams mp3s from the web, proxied through a local HTTP server. At times, this local proxy server returns an HTTP error. It seems that upon receiving this error during the prepare state, the MediaPlayer makes one more attempt to stream, sending another request to the URL specified in setDataSource().

From a thread, I'm calling MediaPlayer.prepare() once. But from the proxy thread, I can see that after sending an HTTP error response, another request for the same URL is made. Can someone confirm this behavior? I'm seeing this from the emulator running a 1.6 AVD.

Can I disable this automatic retry? Is there a specific HTTP error code that I can send that will prevent this retry?

Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't depend on the behavior not to change, but have you tried to track down and examine the source on android.git.kernel.org?

Comment: I've looked, but I'm not familiar with the structure of the player framework enough to really discern what's going on.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Im running into this aswell. I can see the MediaPlayer tries 3-8 times to get the stream. Setting different statuscodes doesn't work.

Comment: CasperSkoubo my solution at the time, if I recall (this was several years ago), was to retry in a loop several times until it worked.